# Screen Recording permission in Catalina using plist

Tags: macos, electron, plist, macos-catalina

I'm creating a remote desktop streaming application on macOS. Recently macOS introduced screen recording permissions in Catalina. It shows a popup to allow screen recording.

Use Case:
Allowing an application for recording screen for WebRTC implementation. To run this application all the time (always running) i'm using plist.

Problem:
When i'm executing my binary from command line then it's showing that popup but when i'm running the same binary through PLIST then it's not asking for permission and i'm unable to give screen recording permission.

Comment: I have the same issue (see [here](https://github.com/nomeata/arbtt/issues/30)). I found this question also in the [Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/127184), but no answer yet.